# Extending Bootstrap sidebar to end of webpage

Tags: html, css, flask, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to extend the red sidebar of my webpage. Currently it looks like so:

[image: Current sidebar]

I am using Bootstrap in conjunction with Flask, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to extend all the way to the bottom of the page. I have tried using `flex` and more but nothing seems to change it. My code is as follows:

My HTML file:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 sidebar-offcanvas">
                <nav id="side" class="sidebar-nav">

                    {% block sidebar %}

                    {% endblock sidebar %}

                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="content-wrapper" class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                {% block content %}

                {% endblock content %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The relevant parts of my CSS file:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    background: darkred;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem:**

What you're seeing is that your .sidebar-nav is filling 100% of it's parent, however, the parent is not 100% percent of the screen. This causes your sidebar to be shorter than you'd like. I believe this is specifically caused by your row div.

**The Solution:**

Create a class you can use to apply max view height to your row div:

```
.maxVH {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then add this class to your row div:

```
<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left maxVH">
```

That will extend the row to match the view height and subsequently your sidebar will expand to fill it.

The way you can figure that out is by exploring your elements in the developer's console to see what the first parent element that isn't expanding to 100% of the page is and then add CSS to cause that element to give you the desired behavior.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but unfortunately that didn't fix the issue. I tried the trick you mentioned with the developer console, and I think I am still running into the same issue you described.

Comment: What element are you seeing that isn't matching the page height?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have a Navigation Bar at the top. Adding to Ryan Gibbs answer I did something like:

```
.maxVH {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

`56px` is the default height for a navigation bar.